# How do I make su wait before retries in freebsd?

Tags: freebsd, timeout, su, bsd

I want to make attempts at using the su command timeout for 1 second between tries.  Alas, the Google and StackExchange, and rtfm have not yielded results.

Comment: I don't see anything in the source code for su or pam modules that implement delays. (Linux pam has a few modules that can be configured to delay). You could always modify the source to sleep before exiting. If your particular use case is to hinder people trying to su to root, you can add authorized users to group 0 (`wheel`); any other users won't even be allowed to try to su to root.